# Is it possible to speedup animations on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, frame-rate

I'm playing a web game on Chrome, and this game has some pretty slow menu animations.
As far as I know this game is made in html5.

I would like to know if somehow there is a way to increase the framerate on Chrome so the animations on the game would go faster.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling hardware acceleration on Chrome setting could somehow help.